# How to create materialized view log on the remote database

Tags: oracle, database-administration, materialized-views, database-link

Here our issue is we have to create materialized view logs on the remote database's base tables

for respective materialized views on the local database

Both local and remote databases are Oracle 11g (11.2)

example:
 s1 and s2 are two schemas

s1 schema is on the local databse
s2 schema is on the remote databae

we have to create materialized view logs on the s2 schema(Remote database)

we created database link for accessing the s2 schema's objects(Remote database)

But we are getting this error ORA-00949 'illegal reference to remote database'

But in s1 schema(local database) we are able to creating  the materialized views

Thanks

Ragav

Answer (score 3):

There's supposed to be no problem with creating **Mviews** which perform **Fast Refresh** (refreshing an mview using mview log on target table) querying tables which are located on a **remote site**.

What you need to do:

1. Create a **database link** between the two Oracle databases
2. Perform a testing that the db link actually work (run a few queries on the "target table")
3. On the remote site — create **mview log** on the target table
4. Create mview on the local database with **Fast Refresh** option (with for example - refresh on demand) and query the target table in the mview's SQL (for example `select name, date from target_schema.target_table@remote_oracle_db;`)
5. Now, run a complete refresh on your mview: `dbms_snapshot.refresh('local_schema.mview_x','c');`
6. From now on, you can refresh the mview using the Fast Refresh option: `dbms_snapshot.refresh('local_schema.mview_x','f');`

Comment: Would this be possible if the remote DB is MSSQL?  Would there be a way to create the mview log on MSSQL??

Comment: "materialized view logs" are an Oracle Database feature.

Comment: Hi Golosovsky,  Thank-you for your answer and your original post on how to do fast refreshes on a remote Oracle DB.  My question is, is there a way to do fast refreshes on a non-oracle remote db??  Can fast refresh only be done on oracle dbs??

Comment: Yes. It's a feature of Oracle databases.